# How to share Child component data into Parent Component uisng context API into Reactjs

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

I want to share Child Component (Product.js) data into Parent Component (App.js) without button click. I will use useState with context API. I don't know how to passed this data without click event.

Product.js data display into console.log() into App.js component.

App.js

```
import React from 'react';
import Product from './Product';

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Product />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Product.js

```
import React from 'react';

const Product = () => {
    return (
        <div>
           Product Name: <input type="text" />
           <br />
           Description:- <input type="text" />
        </div>
    )
}

export default Product
```

Please help I have no advance knowledge of react.

Comment: It doesn't look like there is any [Context API](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html) code in what you've posted. What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are three ways to share information without click event with useContext and useState.

1. useContext
2. useState in childComponent
3. useState in parentComponent

**1. useContext**

```
import { createContext, useContext, useState } from 'react';

import React from 'react';

const Context = createContext();

const Product = () => {
  const [info, setInfo] = useContext(Context);
  return (
    <div>
      Product Name: <input type="text" value={info.name} onChange={(e) => {
      setInfo({ ...info, name: e.target.value });
    }} />
      <br />
      Description:- <input type="text" value={info.desc} onChange={(e) => {
      setInfo({ ...info, desc: e.target.value });
    }} />
    </div>
  );
}

function App() {
  const [info, setInfo] = useState({
    name: '',
    desc: ''
  });

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Context.Provider value={[info, setInfo]}>
        <Product />
      </Context.Provider>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

> If you have each component in a file. You have to create the context in a third file and import it from the parent and child component.

**2. useState in childComponent**

```
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';

import React from 'react';

const Product = ({ setParentInfo }) => {
  const [info, setInfo] = useState({ name: '', desc: '' });
  useEffect(() => {
    setParentInfo(info);
  }, [info])
  return (
    <div>
      Product Name: <input type="text" value={info.name} onChange={(e) => setInfo({ ...info, name: e.target.value  })} />
      <br />
      Description:- <input type="text" value={info.desc} onChange={(e) => setInfo({ ...info, desc: e.target.value  })} />
    </div>
  )
}

let info = { name: '', desc: '' }

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Product setParentInfo={(newInfo) => {
        info = { ...newInfo };
      }} />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

**3. useState in parentComponent**

```
import { useState } from 'react';

import React from 'react';

const Product = ({ info, setParentInfo }) => {
  return (
    <div>
      Product Name: <input type="text" value={info.name} onChange={(e) => setParentInfo({ ...info, name: e.target.value  })} />
      <br />
      Description:- <input type="text" value={info.desc} onChange={(e) => setParentInfo({ ...info, desc: e.target.value  })} />
    </div>
  )
}


function App() {
  const [info, setInfo] = useState({ name: '', desc: '' });
  console.log("parent: ", info);
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Product info={info} setParentInfo={(newInfo) => {
        setInfo({ ...newInfo });
      }} />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

*I hope I've helped you. Have a nice day!*

Comment: I tryed with useContext. It is working. Thanks a lot for support.

Answer (score 0):

### If its a direct child to parent communication, it's better to done this using props. Less code, works fine!

##### App.js:-

```js
import React from 'react';
import Product from './Product';

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Product 
         onProductNameChange={productName => console.log(productName)} 
         onProductDescChange={productDesc => console.log(productDesc)}
      />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

---

##### Product.js:-

```js
import React from 'react';

const Product = ({onProductNameChange, onProductDescChange}) => {
    return (
        <div>
           Product Name: <input type="text" onChange={e => onProductNameChange(e.target.value)} />
           <br />
           Description:- <input type="text" onChange={e => onProductDescChange(e.target.value)} />
        </div>
    )
}

export default Product
```

Answer (score 0):

Share information without click event with useContext and useState.

App.js

```
import React from 'react';
import Store from './Store';

import ProductList from './ProductList';

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Store>
      <ProductList />
      </Store>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

ProductList.js

```
import React, { useContext } from 'react';
import { Context } from './Store';
import Product from './Product';
import AddProduct from './AddProduct';

const ProductList = () => {

  const [state, setState] = useContext(Context);

  console.log(state);

  return (
    <>
      <AddProduct />
      <Product />
    </>
  )
}

export default ProductList
```

AddProduct.js

```
import React, { useContext} from 'react';
import { Context} from './Store';

const AddProduct = () => {
    const [products, setProducts] = useContext(Context);


    return (
        <div>
            Description:- <input type="text" 
            onChange={(e) => setProducts({ ...products, Description: e.target.value })}/>
        </div>
    )
}

export default AddProduct
```

Product.js

```
import React, { useContext} from 'react';
import { Context} from './Store';

const Product = () => {
const [products, setProducts] = useContext(Context);

    return (
        <>
<h2>Product</h2>
<p>Description: {products.Description}</p>
        </>
    )
}

export default Product
```

Store.js

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

const product = {
    Description: '',
};

export const Context = React.createContext();

const Store = ({ children}) => {
    const [products, setProducts] = useState(product);

    return (
        <Context.Provider value={[products, setProducts]}>{children}</Context.Provider>
    );
};

export default Store;
```